# Gunicorn over Flask sending Parallel requests to same route

Tags: python, flask, promise, gunicorn, htop

I am running a Flask application (fewer users, organization level). I have a high-end machine, with 72 cores and 515703MB RAM.

I am currently running my application as (no nginx):

```
gunicorn --workers=10 --threads=12 -b 0.0.0.0:5000 "run:app" --access-logfile user_activity_logs/user_activity.log --preload
```

i.e. 120 process threads (Ideally, there is flexibility ~ 2*72 + 1 process threads).

There is a paginate API that needs to send huge data approx 60-70MB of rows from a CSV in small chunks of 1-2 MB.

For these, I am sending n (no. of pages) requests in parallel from Frontend. But on some dates, n is around 25-30 pages or even more.

From `networks` and `htop`, what I am seeing is initial 4 requests seem to be fast and parallel, but the later requests follow less speed and follow a pattern i.e. around 4 requests at a time in parallel and keep remaining pending.

**Frontend Code:**

```
const page_size = 20000;

async function fetchInitDetails() {
    return await fetchApi('/paginate-refdata/init', {
        "method": "GET",
        "data": {
            'date': $('#date').val(),
            'exchange': $('#exchange').val(),
            'page_size': page_size
        }
    })
}

async function fetchAllPages(initDetails) {
    let columns = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < show_columns.length; i++) {
        if (initDetails.columns.includes(show_columns[i])) {
            if(show_columns[i] == 'expiry_date') {
                columns.push({
                    headerName: titleCase(show_columns[i]),
                    field: show_columns[i],
                    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
                    minWidth: 150,
                    sort: 'desc', 
                    sortIndex: 0
                })
            } else {
                columns.push({
                    headerName: titleCase(show_columns[i]),
                    field: show_columns[i],
                    filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
                    minWidth: 150,
                })
            }
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < initDetails.columns.length; i++) {
        if (!show_columns.includes(initDetails.columns[i])) {
            columns.push({
                headerName: titleCase(initDetails.columns[i]),
                field: initDetails.columns[i],
                filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
                minWidth: 150,
                hide: true
            })
        }
    }

    grid.ref_db.gridOptions.columnDefs = columns;

    const { total_pages } = initDetails;
    const parallelRequests = Array.from({ length: total_pages }, (_, index) => index + 1);
    let pages = 1;
    // (data.total - data.cnt) / 15000 * 10
    const responses = await Promise.all(parallelRequests.map(async (page) => {
        const response =  await fetchApi('/paginate-refdata', {
            "method": "GET",
            "data": {
                'date': $('#date').val(),
                'exchange': $('#exchange').val(),
                'page_size': page_size,
                'page': page
            }
        });
        show_loader(pages/initDetails.total_pages * 100, (initDetails.total_pages - pages++) * 1.2, rerender_html=false);
        // pages++;
        return response;
    }));

    return responses;
}

fetchInitDetails()
.then(initDetails => fetchAllPages(initDetails))
.then(responses => {
    let rows_data = []
    for(let i=0;i<responses.length;i++) {
        for(let j=0;j<responses[i]['data'].length;j++) {
            rows_data.push(responses[i]['data'][j]);
        }
    }
    grid['ref_db'].renderGrid(rows_data);
    Swal.fire({
        toast: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Data loaded',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5000,
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    grid['ref_db'].renderGrid([]);
})
.finally(() => {
    onclose();
})
```

**Backend Code:**

```
@blueprint.route('/paginate-refdata')
@login_required
def paginate_refdata():
    try:
        date = request.args['date'].replace('-', '')
        exchange = request.args['exchange'].lower()
        page = int(request.args['page'])
        page_size = int(request.args.get('page_size', '10'))
    except:
        return jsonify({ 'msg': 'Please provide date, exchange & page', 'status': False }), 400

    refdata_df = get_or_load_refdata_from_cache(exchange, date)

    total_pages = int(len(refdata_df) / page_size) + 1
    curr_page = paginate_array(refdata_df, page_size, page).to_dict('records')
    result = {
        'page': page,
        'total_pages': total_pages,
        'page_size': len(curr_page),
        'total': len(refdata_df),
        'data': curr_page,
    }
    
    response = Response(gzip.compress(JSON.dumps(result).encode('utf-8')), content_type='application/json')
    response.headers['Content-Encoding'] = 'gzip'
    return response
```

I want to make this webserver utilise the resources and process all 30 requests in parallel as currently it is taking around 2-3 mins as using only 4 workers, it seems and I am expecting it to finish in <10secs, as 1 request takes around 3 secs of time.

Can anyone please help me and let me know where I am missing or wrong.

**EDIT :**

I tested with ab and it seems concurrent, as all processes now seem to have non 0 CPU% in htop

`seq 1 300 | xargs -n 1 -P 300 -I {} ab -n 1 -c 1 "10.40.1.56:5000/…{}&page_size=10000"`

but from browser actually 6 requests initially are in parallel in logs and then incrementally other requests come

Comment: (1) What does `get_or_load_refdata_from_cache` do? Can the _cache_, whatever it is, have a lock that limits parallelism? (2) Based on `to_dict('records')` you're using Pandas – you probably shouldn't be. (3) What is `JSON.dumps()`? If you need a fast JSON encoder, use `orjson`. (4) Have you benchmarked your server with just a basic HTTP benchmark tool such as `ab` to see that it can actually peg all cores? (5) And of course, you should instrument your code with profiling to know what's actually happening.

Comment: (1) get_or_load_refdata_from_cache: checks cache (redis here), if the key is there it loads it (pickled pandas df) else it reads the CSV, makes pandas df out of it pickle it and set to redis (2) Okay, but I need to send list of dict as response (3) Ok I'll check this (4) let me check with ab

Comment: (1) Make sure you do end up reading the data from Redis all the time then instead of accidentally parsing CSV. Pickling/unpickling can also be slow. (2) Why not just save the list-of-dicts in the cache? Or, if you're already using Redis as a kind of a database, use a Redis list of JSON strings; you can read its length and slice it in Redis (`LLEN`, `LRANGE`), and concatenate it into your response.

Comment: I tested with ab and it seems concurrent, as all processes now seem to have non 0 CPU% in htop

seq 1 300 | xargs -n 1 -P 300 -I {} ab -n 1 -c 1 "http://10.40.1.56:5000/paginate-refdata?date=20240103&exchange=uscom&page={}&page_size=10000"

(2) yes it is reading from redis for non-1st request, Okay I'll check "Redis list of JSON strings".


agree it will fast it up, but is it browser which is restricting up to 4 parallel req?

Comment: Browsers have a limit as to how many concurrent requests they like to make per host, yes.

Comment: Agree, is there a way I can enforce or something  ..?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/985431/51685 for more on that topic.